# $session->get is empty after site migration

Tags: php, joomla

I am in progress of migrating an existing website to AWS. But there's one thing tha works fine on the current site, but simply wont work on the new one, whatever I try.
I have a php script in Joomla that does:

```
  $session = JFactory::getSession();
  $session->set('user_name', '$user_name');
```

and another script that does:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$name = $session->get('user_name' , '' );
```

$name is empty and I cant figure out why. On the working site that I migrate away from, the code works. So I guess there must be some Joomla parameter to set somewhere to activate this, but I cant figure out where that would be.

Answer (score 0):

Session issues in Joomla are extremely complex. There are many issues that might be causing this problem:

- wrong tmp/log paths in the `configuration.php` file (have you updated those paths on the new website)
- database issues on the new server
- `.htaccess` lines that are incompatible with the new server. Try disabling the `.htaccess` file and see if that fixes the problem. (we have just had a session problem caused by the `.htaccess`. Read [this post](http://www.itoctopus.com/yet-another-login-loop-in-joomlas-backend) if you are interested).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I checked the link you gave and added the plg_user_joomla that was missing. This improved the situation but doesnt fix it yet.
Now the situation is such that the session variables get written, but I can only access them after I do a 'refresh' on the new page. It looks like there is a problem of session variables being written delayed or that they need some kind of commit. 
Is there anything else I can look at?